# Macbook Pro battery drains quickly; bluetooth often malfunctions

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, bluetooth, sleep-wake

I have an early 2015 Macbook Pro running Monterey 12.5.1. About a year ago my computer was constantly entering into a kernel panic; it turned out that the battery was bloated and pressing up against the rest of the innards, and a local computer repair shop successfully replaced it. There were no subsequent issues for a long time.

In the last couple months, I have noticed that my laptop seems to wake itself up – when I leave it open overnight (i.e. lid not closed, but still on screensaver/asleep), it will wake itself up during the night but not getting any login it goes back to sleep, only to repeat about 20 minutes later.

In the last month or so it seems to even do this when it is shut; it will get very warm, and most worryingly of all, seems to discharge very fast without being plugged in, even with the clamshell shut. I would say that the battery lasts no more than a few hours most of the time without charging, whether clamshell up or down.

One distinct but strange behavior. In the last couple months, I have found that it won't always connect to bluetooth; on the menu up top it will say that bluetooth is on but there are no devices to connect to, then when I enter System Preferences and try to click "Bluetooth", System Prefernces stalls (no beach ball or anything, but it won't let me click anything else) before giving a pop-up that it can't enter bluetooth settings. Usually after an hour or so it will let me connect to bluetooth. I raise this only as a possibly-related issue.

With all this being said, does anyone know what is going on with my laptop, or what I should check for? It works fine other than these issues along with slight slowdowns that I chalk up to just being not especially new.

Comment: First thing I would do is check for third-party software that is scheduled to run in the background -- LaunchAgents, Launch Daemons, etc.

Comment: I have a backup service that I believe is scheduled to run at night, but I’ve had it for years; should I try disabling it for some time to see if it changes anything?

Comment: It's worth testing, certainly. And make sure it's updated to the latest version, at least. Old software of this sort on new OS is frequently a cause of problems.